# Resize image height to match flex parent height

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, parent

I have an oversized image that I would like to adjust to the height of its parent but it keeps on adjusting the height of the parent to match the default image height. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I need the image to obey the parent height, not the other way around.

Please see my code for a better understanding:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Code snippet has been updated since original post

Comment: maybe without `height: 400px` or change to `min-height`

Comment: If I take them out of the flow then the siblings ignore the margins I have. (not referring to above code)

Comment: maybe post a code answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add

```
 overflow:hidden;
 flex: 1;
```

to item

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  overflow:hidden;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Try: https://jsbin.com/tejezuq/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Although this solution worked for the miniature example I provided, it didn't seem to work to the application I am working on (which I don't understand why).

Comment: So we need to understand the complete structure then... I can check & help you if you have the complete non-working base in Plunker (Or similar)

Comment: Updated my answer, please check and let me know if it is still not helping you.

Comment: list height cannot be 100% as it is flexed inside a flex box. imagine there are 2 lists, height needs to be set to `flex: 1`

Comment: Got it, so container height should be 200 and flex 1; But image should obey the height of the container... Am I Correct?

Comment: container height is fixed, however list height is flexed `flex: 1` - all list items height should be equal and image heights should match list item height

Answer (score 0):

<s>height: 400px</s>

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="placeholder">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Imagine `container` has to be 400px in height, then what?